# Colorful dots on laptop screen

Tags: dell-inspiron, laptop-display

I have a Dell laptop 3510 model and it has a weird issue. As soon as it boots up it alternates between black and colorful dotted screen and then it turns off. And in this time everything else stops working too.
What can be the problem? 
Herr are the screenshots. Please ignore the permanent vertical lines. 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jna97m7q1nlgm19/AACGHIM64oB6jK1uHCg4k7Era?dl=0

Comment: It could be a broken videocard. How old is the laptop? Do you still have warranty?

Comment: @LPChip it's 3 years old so no warranty. If it's broken video card then why everything else stops working?

Comment: A busted video card will indeed stop the system from doing anything, as it's an integral part of the system.